# Build a gatsby plugin for elastic app search - get graphql querys

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I want to create a local gatsby plugin to index graphql querys in elastic app search.

My problem is, how I can get the articles with a graphql query as an array.
I need a structure like this:

```
const documents = [
{
id: 'INscMGmhmX4',
url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INscMGmhmX4',
title: 'The Original Grumpy Cat',
body: 'A wonderful video of a magnificent cat.'
},
{
id: 'JNDFojsd02',
url: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ',
title: 'Another Grumpy Cat',
body: 'A great video of another cool cat.'
}
]
```

This is my query I want to index from Strapi:

```
const myQuery = `  
     {
      allStrapiKbArticles {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            title
            content
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
```

Here is my current code of the gatsby-node.js file:

```
const chunk = require('lodash.chunk');
const report = require('gatsby-cli/lib/reporter');
const AppSearchClient = require ('@elastic/app-search-node');

let activity = report.activityTimer(`Indexing to ElasticSearch`); 



exports.onCreateDevServer = async function (

    { graphql },
    { baseUrlFn,  apiKey, queries, chunkSize = 1000 }
  ) {
    activity.start();
  
    const client = new AppSearchClient(undefined, apiKey, baseUrlFn)
    
  
    setStatus(activity, `${queries.length} queries to index`);
  
    const jobs = queries.map(async function doQuery(
      { engineName: engineName, query, transformer = identity, indexConfig },
      i
    ) {
      if (!query) {
        report.panic(
          `failed to index to Elastic. You did not give "query" to this query`
        );
      }
     
    setStatus(activity, `query ${i}: executing query`);
    const result = await graphql((query)
    ).then(result => console.log(result))
 
     activity.end();
}) 
}
```

Error:   TypeError: graphql is not a function (const result = await graphql((query))

Comment: why not https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/third-party-graphql/ and  https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-strapi ?

Comment: @xadm I use the strapi plugin to  get the data from there. But I struggle with the code in the gatsby-node.js file of the own plugin. There is an algolia index plugin. But I don't understand how they coded the part with graphql

Comment: using any graphql client? even simplest fetch/axios can do that

Comment: @xadm yes, the client comes with gatsby.

Comment: yes, gatsby provides own, limited client (provided f.e. to createPages) and own 'server' (not real server) - both for internal gatsby usage, not for external calls

Comment: @xadm Ok, but I tested it although with md files in the query (locally) and it doesn't work. Primarly my question is, why I get the error "graphql" is not a function. Can you tell me how they do it: https://github.com/algolia/gatsby-plugin-algolia/blob/master/gatsby-node.js

Comment: I tested the algolia plugin in onCreateDevServer and it get the same error. So maybe the graphql stuff not works in develop mode?

Comment: it could be a reason for their plugin ... for your code ... not graphql passed into this 'injection point' ... onCreateDevServer gets 'app' arg, use search on github

Comment: So you would use another client for graphql und build the plugin standalone from gatsby?

Comment: why not to index during build, next to createPage calls (standard gatsby-node usage) ?

Comment: Later, I would do that, But when I build gatsby I get no console.logs for troubleshooting.

Comment: for sure there is a method for that ... https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-the-build-process/